# What would be my approach to the user who don't accept answers of their questions

Tags: discussion, support, users

I seen seen many user in SO who barely accepted any answers on their questions.
And what they have accepted most of them are self answer.

What should be my approach or action toward these type of account?

Comment: "Not accepting answers" isn't the same as "not giving feedback"... and users are under no obligation to accept answers.

Comment: edited the title. I know they are under no obligation, but isn't is a bad thing to not to (continuously ) ..@JonSkeet

Comment: I think "bad" is an overstatement, personally... why do you think it should affect how you treat them? Are you answering questions in order to gain rep, or in order to increase the repository of knowledge? While accepted answers give an extra signal, I wouldn't hesitate to answer a decent question asked by someone even if they had a stated *policy* of not accepting answers.

Comment: I dint mean to rude. I am just asking form a ethical point of view @JonSkeet

Comment: Well I'd say from an ethical point of view, you should probably just treat those accounts like any other account. That's my approach, at least.

Comment: I thing marking an answer as accepted means telling other 'This is the most appropriate answer according to my situation'.
which means that answer provide more help than others is the given circumstances (according to who ask the question ).
Personally when I try to find solution of any problem I focus on the accepted answer first and then one with the most vote.
If marking accepted help other user then why  not accepting answer will not be discouraged? @JonSkeet

Comment: In the good old days, there used to be an indicator on the asker's profile that showed the percentage of questions asked, and answers accepted. It gave a good indicator to know if this person is responsive or just one of those `give me the codez` people. Sadly, I don't remember why - they took away that option.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: It led to far too many "ticking off" comments, and people focusing on that one metric when considering whether or not to answer a question, IIRC. I'm *very* glad the indicator has gone.

Comment: just to verify that this is not about me or reputation, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509589/convert-a-collection-of-char-into-string-without-the-comma-and-square-brackets/   
see the answer given by  user: `singhakash` . the asker said in the comment `thanks. it works perfectly`, but neither he gave any vote nor accepted it and then it is the asked question history that bothers me @JonSkeet

Comment: But why does it bother you so much that you consider "actions" towards such users? And heck, that was only an hour ago... maybe the user will accept it later, after seeing whether there are other, better answers. If they don't want to accept an answer, that's fine as far as I'm concerned. It may not be ideal, but it's not something worth making a fuss about.